# UISearchBar - search a NSDictionary of Arrays of Objects

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary, uisearchbar

I'm trying to insert a search bar in a tableview, that is loaded with information from a NSDictionary of Arrays. Each Array holds and object. Each object has several properties, such as Name or Address.

I've implemented the methods of NSSearchBar, but the code corresponding to the search it self, that i have working on another project where the Arrays have strings only, is not working, and I can't get to thr problem.

Here's the code:
'indiceLateral' is a Array with the alphabet;
'partners' is a NSDictionary;
'RLPartnersClass' is my class of Partners, each one with the properties (name, address, ...).

```
-(void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {

 NSMutableArray *sectionsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [self resetSearch];

 for (NSString *key in self.indiceLateral) {
  NSMutableArray *array = [partners valueForKey:key];
  NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for (NSString *name in array) {
   if ([name rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
    [toRemove addObject:name];
  }

  if ([array count] == [toRemove count])
   [sectionsToRemove addObject:key];
  [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
  [toRemove release];
 }

 [self.indiceLateral removeObjectsInArray:sectionsToRemove];

 [sectionsToRemove release];
 [theTable reloadData];
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,

Rui Lopes

Answer (score 5):

I've done it.

Example:

```
-(void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    NSMutableDictionary *finalDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSString *currentLetter = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[indiceLateral count]; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *elementsToDict = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        currentLetter = [indiceLateral objectAtIndex:i];

        NSArray *partnersForKey = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[partnersCopy objectForKey:[indiceLateral objectAtIndex:i]]];

        for (int j=0; j<[partnersForKey count]; j++) {
            RLNames *partnerInKey = [partnersForKey objectAtIndex:j];

            NSRange titleResultsRange = [partnerInKey.clientName rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (titleResultsRange.length > 0){
                NSLog(@"found: %@", partnerInKey.clienteCity
                [elementsToDict addObject:partnerInKey];
            }
        }

        [finalDict setValue:elementsToDict forKey:currentLetter];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *finalResultDict = [finalDict mutableDeepCopy];
    self.partners = finalResultDict;
    [finalResultDict release];

    [theTable reloadData];
}
```