# UISearchBar with a grouped table view -- in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, grouped-table

Forgive me for not being able to figure this out on my own. I picked up iOS at Swift, and didn't learn much of objective-c.

I'm attempting to build in a `uisearchbar` that filters through a grouped table view composed of multiple arrays for it's sections. Essentially, I need to filter through an `NSMutableArray` built of *other* arrays in order to get my search results (normal array couldn't compile in 'reasonable time'). I took a look at [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374359/uisearchbar-in-grouped-section-uitable) and it's getting at what I need, but unfortunately, I'm not the best when it comes to translating Obj-c over to swift, in this case. Any help (translation) or direction to other tutorials that will help me do this is greatly appreciated. I've been searching and searching, and tinkering all night -- but I've caved, I need some help.

**Edit:** still not answered

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to objective-c code but lets start from here

After you create your view controller,table view and search bar components,
In ViewController class, you have to delegate items to ViewController like:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
searchBar.delegate = self
```

And then you have to implement(override) methods like

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -&gt; Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

explained here [Delegation](http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/)

also here's a reference-video [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG_AMY_gSDQ)

hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the question I'm asking :/ I'm trying to filter through an `NSMutableArray` built of *other* arrays. Not simply `.filter` through a simple array. That I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Add these UISearchBarDelegate methods in your class and your class must confirm to this protocol using either code `self.yourSearchBar.delegate = self` or in storyboard.

```
   func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    self.searchedArrayToDisplay = self.listDataArray
}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}


func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText == "\n" {

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    } else if searchText == "" {

    self.searchedArrayToDisplay = self.listDataArray
    } else {

        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchText)
    }
}


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {

    self.searchedArrayToDisplay = self.listDataArray.filter({(eachObject: [String:AnyObject]) -> Bool in

        let name = eachObject["name"] as! String
        let stringMatch = name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString)
        let result = stringMatch != nil ? true : false
        return result
    })
}
```

Now in cell for at index path method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
        var object = self.searchedArrayToDisplay[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Ok this is making sense, however, you cannot use `.filter()` on an `NSMutableArray` as you have in `filterContentForSearchText`. My "`listdataArray`", as you've put it, is an NSMutableArray. That command is not a member. I believe you have to use `NSPredicate` or some variation??

Comment: Also, I tried simple casting the `NSMutableArray` as a normal array in order to use the `.filter`. But I'm getting an error: 
'Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(([String : AnyObject]) -> Bool)' ...any suggestions for either of these?

Comment: This one i did using Swift Array. if you are using NSMutableArray, you need to use some other logic. By the way why not you are using swift array. Its easy.

Comment: Because a swift array could not compile within reasonable time. It's a very large array of data. Any idea how to go about the logic for doing this with `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains [c] %@", argumentArray: [searchText])
        self.listDataArray.filterUsingPredicate(predicate) Something like this you need to do.

Comment: This will not work with bool. I just gave you the predicate.If you want i can give the full code.

Comment: I would be very grateful for the full code. I'm completely stuck here

Comment: Hello @Amit89, could you still provide the code for this?